# Is there a name for this characteristic of the human body (picture)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for this characteristic of the human body (see the arrows in the picture below)? They seem as 'holes' on the back.

I'm not able to imagine one

[image: picture of feature]

Answer (score 16):

These holes/depressions are called [**dimples of venus**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimples_of_Venus). Also called **back dimples** or **butt dimples**.

Comment: Hmmm... Venus with that picture.  Me thinks someone is just jonesing for points with a pretty picture...

Comment: @AffableGeek See, the picture isn't pretty anymore.

Answer (score 5):

The single-word you are requesting is "dimples."

Answer (score 2):

These are also called *sacral dimples*, as the lower back is the sacrum.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved if you could link to an authoritative reference. The [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) may also provide beneficial guidance.